# I guest can edit an event that can't be modify ( (event created from apps script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I created a script that generates periodic events from the apps script console, via a form contained in a sidebar. For each series, I invite a person from my organization and I forbid him the right to modify the events of the series. When an event type is created, I assign it a calendar that is not shared with anyone. The problem is that the guest can modify the event. this is my function:

```
function createEventSeries(formObject, calendrier, reccurence, acronymePresta) {
    var titre = formObject.dossier + " " + acronymePresta + " n°" + formObject.numPresta + " S";
    return calendrier.createEventSeries(
        titre,
        new Date(formObject.startTime),
        new Date(formObject.endTime),
        reccurence,
        {
            description: "",
            guests: formObject.guestEmail,
            sendInvites: formObject.isSendInvit,
            guestsCanModify: false  // Ajout de cette ligne pour empêcher les invités de modifier l'événement
        }
    );
}
```

and now, how i call my function with a

```
sleep: var eventSeries = createEventSeries(formObject, calendrier, reccurence, acronymePresta);
    Utilities.sleep(5000);
```

The result is that the guest can modify the event.

Can you help me?

Regard